# How to throw an ArgumentNullException on a property

Tags: c#

I have a method where it checks if a property is null or not. I know how to throw an arguement null exception if the object is null but how do you throw an arguementnullexception for a property on the object.

```
private int CalculateCompletedDateDiff(Recall recall)
{
    if (!recall.StartDate.HasValue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("recall.StartDate");
    }

    //calculate and return
}
```

I am using resharper and there is purple scriggly under `recall.StartDate` that says cannot resolve symbol. So, if the StartDate cannot be null what is the correct way to throw an arguementnull exception on the startdate property?

Comment: It will be indicating that recall could be null - that's why and to do a check on the object for null before evaluating.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't throw `ArgumentNullException` if the argument (`recall`) isn't null. Just `ArgumentException` is appropriate here when it's some problem with the argument other than it being null:

```
if (recall == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("recall");
}
if (recall.StartDate == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("StartDate of recall must not be null",
                                "recall");
}
```

Comment: @k4rlsson: nope. Nullable type does the right thing with the equality operator (and why wouldn't it?).

Comment: Wow an elegant solution indeed.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper is *probably* suggesting that you do a null reference check on `recall` before de-referencing it?  Maybe something like this:

```
if (recall == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("recall");
if (!recall.StartDate.HasValue)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("recall.StartDate");
```

Semantically I'm not sure if this is really the proper use of an `ArgumentNullException`, though.  Since `StartDate` isn't an argument to the method.  This may be personal opinion, but I'd recommend putting the logic for the validity of `StartDate` into the `Recall` object itself.  Of course, the logic to define that isn't known from the question, so it's really just thinking out loud at this point.